# C# / Visual Studio - MSBuild Not Running

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, teamcity

I am trying to build a program for x64, but I keep getting the following error messages:

> Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (3049,5): error MSB4216: The GenerateResource task could not be executed because MSBuild does not create a task host or connect to a task host with runtime CLR4 and architecture x86 "could produce. Make sure that (1) the requested runtime and / or architecture is available on the computer and (2) the required executable file "C: \ Program Files \ dotnet \ sdk \ 2.1.402 \ MSBuild.exe "exists and can be executed.

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise

Comment: Your solution may not be supported by msbuild in .NET Core SDK

Comment: Did you have .NET Core SDK 2.1.402 installed?

Comment: I had the same problem and I've solved it by removing a Windows Forms project from the Solution.